# what is centos LiveCD?

Tags: linux, centos

Reference: https://projects.centos.org/trac/livecd/wiki

I am not able to find what the LiveCD means?

Does it mean that I can run the OS on the CD without any installation on the local machine?

Comment: Yes, LiveCDs are bootable into an environment that runs something, without you needing to install it. This is the first result for searching: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Livecd

Comment: The first result I got is through the key word 'what is centos livecd'. I'd better just search livecd.

Answer (score 5):

A live CD, live DVD, or live disc is a complete bootable computer operating system which runs in the computers memory, rather than loading from the hard disk drive

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_CD

This gives you the ability to try the OS without having to install it